# What's the policy on showing images of neglected or sick animals?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, asking-questions

As simple as the title reads. There are many relevant cases of animal neglect which could well be on topic for the site. If showing images, should these be hidden? What sort of NSFW policy applies for this site that deals with animal health?

What's the policy on showing images of neglected or sick animals?

Comment: related ish http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/where-is-the-line-drawn-for-feeder-animals

Comment: A couple of the more graphic existing questions [Will owls attack small dogs?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8126) & [What can I do for my turtle that fell down three floors?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6245)

Comment: @JamesJenkins yep that pretty much answers my question. What's the format to hide images?

Answer (score 2):

Use a spoiler markup '>!' to hide content

> like this, if the image is behind it you cant see the image.

Mouse over to see the content, you can hit edit on this question to see how I wrote it.

Comment: hm the edit button is disabled. Wonder if this is a bug or by design

Comment: @Yvette You might not have enough rep yet.  They don't use it much at SO, which is the only place you have high rep.  You just start the line with >! (*leave a space*) everything following is hidden.

Comment: Yeh I think it's just the meta posts, as it's not disabled on the main site.

Comment: asked Q on meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285484/meta-edit-buttons-disabled-and-not-on-main-site-pets. Yeh I don't usually attempt to edit posts on meta anywhere except SO.

Comment: Interesting about edits on meta, you should be able to use the edit button on the two examples I have in the comments under your question.